# Finding the indexed location of values in a unsorted numpy array from data in another unsorted numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array A which contains unique IDs that can be in any order  - e.g. A = [1, 3, 2]. I have a second numpy array B, which is a record of when the ID is used - e.g. B = [3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1]. Array B is always much longer than array A.

I need to find the indexed location of the ID in A for each time the ID is used in B. So in the example above my returned result would be: result = [1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0].

I've already written a simple solution that gets the correct result using a for loop to append the result to a new list and using numpy.where, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to vectorize this.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 3, 2])
B = np.array([3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1])

IdIndxs = []
for ID in B:
    IdIndxs.append(np.where(A == ID)[0][0])

IdIndxs = np.array(IdIndxs)
```

Can someone come up with a simple vector based solution that runs quickly - the for loop becomes very slow when running on a typical problem where is A is of the size of 10K-100K elements and B is some multiple, usually 5-10x larger than A.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but I just can't see it today.

Comment: If you values were sorted, you could have used `digitize` or `searchsorted`. But, alas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import numpy as np

# test data
A = np.array([1, 3, 2])
B = np.array([3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1])

# get indexes
sorted_keys = np.argsort(A)
indexes = sorted_keys[np.searchsorted(A, B, sorter=sorted_keys)]
```

Output:

```
[1 1 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 1 1 0]
```

Comment: Do you need `searchsorted`? You coud do: `indexes=np.argsort(A)[B-1]`

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy-indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) library (disclaimer: I am its author) was designed to provide these type of vectorized operations where numpy for some reason does not. Frankly given how common this vectorized list.index equivalent is useful it definitely ought to be in numpy; but numpy is a slow-moving project that takes backwards compatibility very seriously, and I dont think we will see this until numpy2.0; but until then this is pip and conda installable with the same ease.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = npi.indices(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reworking your logic but using a list comprehension and [numpy.fromiter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) which should boost performance.

```
IdIndxs = np.fromiter([np.where(A == i)[0][0] for i in B], B.dtype)
```

#### About performance

I've done a quick test comparing `fromiter` with your solution, and I do not see such boost in performance. Even using a B array of millions of elements, they are of the same order.